# Did Umar Say That if There Was Not Ali , Then He undoubtedly killed?

Tags: sunni, hadith-interpretation, uloom-al-hadith

Some Shiites believes that Umar (Arabic: عمر بن الخطاب, translit.: `Umar ibn Al-Khattāb) the second caliphate declared a famous sayings which designated on outranking and overriding of Ali.

I want to know first do Sunnis accept the sayings? if yes how they interpret it?
the saying is as follow:" Umar said:

> if was not Ali , I will be killed undoubtedly

We want to know more about Sunni's  attitude about the saying. now here I mention some sources among Sunni and Shiite referred to the saying:

Sunni source:

> - Ibn Qutaybah,Tavil Mokhtalaf Al HAdith,p.152
> - Taftazani,sharhe Maqasid, vol.2,p.294
> - Fakhr Razi, Tafsir KAbir,vol.21,p.22

Shiite source:

> - Sheikh Koleini, al Kafi , vol.7.p 424
> - sheikh Tousi,TAhzib,vol.6.p606

Comment: What famous sayings?  As written, this question is just too vague to be answerable; I would recommend you go through the advice in our help centre: "[How Do I Ask a Good Question?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Comment: it is very popular sayings among  Muslim that UMar al Khattab Said such a saying. as it is clear, there is no pay attention to the question mentioned above. of course again I repeat the question in detail box.

Comment: I for one never heard this saying, and i am a sunni